# django 1.8 custom validation of form not working

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-forms

Im learning **django 1.8**(python 2.7.8) and i was trying to validate the email,firstname and lastname field.The problem is what ever i insert into form it gets saved to database(only default email validation is working). Below are what my form,view,model and admin files look like.Any suggestions ? Thank you

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class SignUp(models.Model):
email = models.EmailField()
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True,null=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True,null=True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.email
```

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
# Register your models here.

from .models import SignUp
class SignUpAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["__unicode__","first_name","last_name","timestamp","updated"]
    class Meta:
        model = SignUp

admin.site.register(SignUp, SignUpAdmin)
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from forms import SignUpForm

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    title = "Welcome"
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
    context = { "title": title,"form":form, }
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import SignUp
import re

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SignUp
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','email']
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email_base, provider = email.split('@')
        domain,extension = provider.split('.')
        if provider.count('.')  > 2: #email provider should not have more than 2 "dots=> ."
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please use valid email address")
        return email
    def clean_first_name(self):
        first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        if bool(re.search('[\d\s]',first_name)): #firstname should not have whitespace or digits
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please dont use numbers or space in Name Field")
        return first_name
    def clean_last_name(self):
        last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        if bool(re.search('[\d]',last_name)): #lastname should not have digits
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please dont use numbers or space in Name Field")
        return last_name
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$','newsletter.views.home', name='home'),
        ]
```

## home.html

```
<html>
<title>Home Page</title>
<body>
{{ title }} {{ request.user }} <br>
    <form method="post" action="">
     {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use ->
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm): 
        email = forms.EmailField(max_length=70, label='email_id')
and remove 'clean_email' function for now

Comment: @GrvTyagi didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did some silly mistakes (indentation). The question is corrected and code is correct on post

Answer (score 0):

Your form.py seems fine.I think you are not displaying the errors in the template HTML.
{% if form.errors %}
{% for errors in form.errors %}
{{ errors }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}